# React Context Typescript issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

This is my AppContext.tsx

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import { Iitem } from "../utils/interfaces";
interface AppContext {
  showModal: boolean;
  setShowModal: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  cart: Array<Iitem>;
  setCart: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<never[]>>;
  currentSelection: object | null;
  setCurrentSelection: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<null>>;
}
export const AppContext = createContext<AppContext>({
  showModal: false,
  setShowModal: () => {},
  cart: [],
  setCart: () => {},
  currentSelection: null,
  setCurrentSelection: () => {},
});

export const AppState: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);
  const [currentSelection, setCurrentSelection] = useState(null);
  return (
    <AppContext.Provider
      value={{
        showModal,
        setShowModal,
        cart,
        setCart,
        currentSelection,
        setCurrentSelection,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

MyComponent.tsx

```
const MyComponent = () => {
 const {setCart} =  useContext(AppContext);
 const myFunc = () => {
   setCart((prevState) => [...prevState, newItem]);
 }
}
```

When I try to call the `setCart` method, TypeScript errors out and if I hover over `(prevState)` it shows:

```
(parameter) prevState: never[]
Argument of type '(prevState: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'.
  Type '(prevState: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to type '(prevState: never[]) => never[]'.
    Type 'any[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2345)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In AppContext interface the type is set to never so change change the type that you expect to be there.

```
interface AppContext {
  showModal: boolean;
  setShowModal: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  cart: Array<Iitem>;
  setCart: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any[]>>;
  currentSelection: object | null;
  setCurrentSelection: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<null>>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to solve the issue

```
cart: Array<Iitem>;
```

and....

```
setCart: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Array<Iitem>>>;
```

and....

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState<Array<Iitem>>([]);
```